# Can the operating system restart a process that is stuck in infinite loop?

Tags: linux, unix

The other day, when doing testing on a Linux server, we observed that under some conditions, one process could die and then started again. After checking the code, we found it was caused by an infinite loop.

This aroused my curiosity how the process went dead and then got started? Is it the OS who detects and determines the abnormal process and get it restarted? If yes, how does that work?

Comment: does your program have system call in the loop?

Comment: Not sure if you care, but a very similar problem is the famous Halting Problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem. There are two common proofs that are exceptionally similar, one uses contradiction and the other is just a direct proof. The contradiction one is slightly easier to understand and basically goes "say we can figure out whether a program will 'halt'... what happens if I run it on [some special program]?" It turns out you reach a contradiction and so it has to be impossible.

Comment: I...don't think so? Do your processes interact with each other? Perhaps the calling process has some logic that does this somewhere?

Comment: To Kyle: You could be right. We do have some availability management mechanism. I think I should learn that first.

Comment: It may be possible that you have set some resource limits on the process. Check the man page for [setrlimit/getrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) - RLIMIT_CPU

Comment: Since this question was closed, I posted another (hopefully more acceptable) one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16250472/1858225

Comment: Interesting question, but SO is maybe not the right place to ask this question because there is no definitive answer for that. Try Programmers SE, but try shift the question more to programming and downplay the OS aspect. Maybe you will be more successful this way. Posting another question on SO won't help you.

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of information and people will end up guessing what happened. We don't know how your program is written - does it include a watchdog program to restart itself when the program is not responsive? We don't know about the set up of your test server - is it set up to restart your program when your program dies?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178130/why-was-this-question-on-detecting-infinite-loops-closed)

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you won't be able to fix your code... And let's ignore all crazy options like attaching `gdb` via script or so.

You can either check CPU usage (most *accidental* infinite loops that I've done used 100% of CPU for hours :) ), or (more likely option) use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to check what the software is doing right now and implement your own *signature tracing* (if those 20 APIs repeats 20 times let's assume infinite loop or so).

For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
strace -p`cat your_app.pid` | ./your_signature_evaluator
# Or
strace -p12345 | ./your_signature_evaluator
```

As for automatic system recognition... It seems normal that program crashes after calling things in loop uncontrollably  (for example `malloc()` until you deplete memory, opening files...), but I've (and correct me in comment if I'm wrong) never seen system (kernel) restarting the app. I think you've either:

- have conditions (signal handling, whatever) inside program that helps to recover
- you're running a watchdog (check every 20 seconds that `<pid>` is running and if not start new instance)
- you're running distribution that provides service/program configuration with *restart if stopped*

But I really doubt that Linux would be so nice to your application on it's own.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the OP's question, which is whether or not the behavior he observed (i.e. the process being stopped and restarted automatically) might have been caused by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If it could the person that wrote that kernel will have solved the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

PS: Vytor - Web servers are in an infinite loop and do not use 100% CPU.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking if the operating system is capable of catching *every* infinite loop--just if it's capable of *noticing* that a process is stuck in one. This is **not** equivalent to the halting problem, because the halting problem has to do with looking at **code** and determining *in advance* whether it will halt rather than *running* the code and waiting to see if it gets caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Hh, I meant *accidental* infinite loops... And AFAIK webservers **do** have terminal conditions (e.g. triggered by `apache2ctl stop` or `net stop ...`) so they are not *infinite loops* in this exact meaning. But point taken ;)

Comment: @KyleStrand - Halting problem and the OP are the same. Your comment about in advance is wrong as (I hate to point this out) computers are deterministic.

Comment: @EdHeal, the halting problem is NOT equivalent to the problem of detecting an infinite loop at run-time. Moreover, the fact that computers are deterministic has nothing to do with whether a loop can (or cannot) be detected at run-time or earlier than that; the entire reason the halting problem is unsolvable is because for any algorithm that attempts to detect non-halting code, there will exist instances of non-halting code such that the *algorithm itself* does not halt.

Comment: (Or, to use Turing's explanation, no Turing machine can determine the behavior of every other Turing machine without simply *emulating it,* i.e., running its "code.")

Comment: @KyleStrand - I beg to differ. You last statement is incorrect - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine

Comment: I've read the *Entscheidungsproblem* paper. What part of that page, exactly, differs with what I said?

Comment: Oops - Missed the "emulating it" bit - but I just think that you have just added it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29021/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-ed-heal)